# Add Zeros to a product number in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have two tables with product numbers. They both are limited to 12 characters (`varchar(12)`). One of them (product A) has a number structure like this:

Product No:

```
2345
568
89
```

And product B has the same exact numbers but with zeros to fill the 12 characters missing. It is something like this:

Product No:

```
000000002345
000000000568
000000000089
```

I just want to modify product A table to add the zeros at the beginning of the sequence. I had an idea with `REPLACE()` function but to add the zeros I might need another function. Thanks for reading and sorry for the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
UPDATE tblA
SET ProductNo = REPLICATE('0', 12 - LEN(ProductNo)) + ProductNo
```

Comment: The option with the RIGHT function also works but for me this is the cleanest way to do it. I liked it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Try this, you can use this statement

```
RIGHT('000000000000'+ISNULL(ProductNo,''),12)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to modify product A table to add the zeros at the beginning of the sequence.

Big hairy question for you:  Are you absolutely certain that you want to store these values in the table with leading zeros, or just be able to display it as-needed with leading zeros?

Reason I ask is because the varchar(12) implies 13 bytes in memory, where an int only takes 4, which will make a big difference if this column participates in indexes and foreign key relationships with other tables.

Comment: Which is bad because the moment someone starts to add characters to what incidentally is a character based identification code your saving comes and hits you into your backside with a lot of force. NEVER do that type of mistake. Use an internal int as number, then put a unique index on the varchar identification code. Most people learned this lesson of not smart savings in the year 2000 problem.